# choose which account to create user

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I created two type of user accounts using Abstractuser.

```
#models.py
class Profile(AbstractUser):
    pass
class first(profile):
    field = # Model field here
class second(profile):
    field = # model field here
```

user creating form here

```
#forms.py
class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')
```

And the view function here

```
#views.py
if form.is_valid():
    new_user = User.objects.create_user(**form.cleaned_data)
    new_user.save()
```

I done with my HTML already to choose which type of account you need to create user account?,  so the user select first then the corresponding field will enable..

This is my question :

Currently `{{ form }}` will render only `username` and `password` and `email` to create account. But I having the lot of fields in first and second account module. how to right `form.py` and also do i need any modification in `views.py` ?

**Edited:**

```
def letsadduser(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        form_first = FirstForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid() and form_first.is_valid():
            User = get_user_model()
            new_user = User.objects.create_user(**form.cleaned_data)

            form_first = Artist()
            form_first.artist_name = request.POST['artist_name']
            form_first.music_genre = request.POST['music_genre']
            form_first.profile_image = request.FILES['profile_image']
            form_first.save()
            new_user.save()
```

The error now is `(1062, "Duplicate entry '' for key 'username'")`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two separate forms, one for each account type. Then in your views.py you should check which type of account is being created and then use the corresponding form.

The form that you posted has `User` as its model, which I guess is the default Django User implementation. You shouldn't use it, instead you should use your specific models.

Overall it looks like you don't quite understand how Django's ModelForm works, I think you'd better read the docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/

Comment: the error is (1062, "Duplicate entry '' for key 'username'") ,.. I ll update my question

Comment: Looks like the username somehow stays empty. If you posted the full traceback and not only the last line it would be quite easier to tell where the error happens.